# Retrieving tail-end of a file path

Tags: python, file, directory, filepath, file-manipulation

I can't find an effective way to do this. The best way to describe what I'm trying to do is by example, so where we go (assuming /bar/ is the parent):

```
C:\foo\bar\baz\text.txt
```

will be my path. I'm interested in everything up to the top-level parent directory of the path. What I need is a script that will do just that. In other words, I want to only grab the

```
\bar\baz\text.txt
```

Split doesn't work for me. It will split the file and the path, but it won't give the output like this. Is there an inbuilt function I'm missing or am I SOL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [`string.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.split):

```
>>> print '\\' + path.split('\\', 2)[-1]
\bar\baz\text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "top-level parent directory".  Your top-level directory is `C:\`.  Parent of what?  If you're trying to get a relative path that starts with the parent of your current working directory, try this:

```
import os.path
os.path.relpath("C:\\foo\\bar\\baz\\text.txt", os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('..')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want, but you may be able to use the little known *rsplit*, which splits from the right side of the string.

```
>>> filepath = r"C:\foo\bar\baz\text.txt"
>>> directories_deep = 3
>>> os.path.sep.join(filepath.rsplit(os.path.sep, directories_deep)[-directories_deep:])
'bar\\baz\\text.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a helper function that does the job:

```
import os
def get_path_tail(path, tail_length = 1):
    assert isinstance(tail_length, int)
    if tail_length == 1:
        return path.split('/')[-tail_length]
    elif tail_length > 1:
        return os.path.join(*path.split('/')[-tail_length:])
```

Behaviour:

```
>>> path = os.path.join('C:','foo','bar', 'baz','text.txt')
>>> print get_path_tail(path, tail_length = 3)

    bar/baz/text.txt
```

Its signature is like that in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036875/1885002) of [ForeverWintr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286571/foreverwintr), but I couldn't comment on his answer as I don't have enough reputation yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [44]: path = 'a/b/c'

In [45]: back = os.path.relpath('.', os.path.join(path, '..'))

In [46]: back
Out[46]: '..\\..'

In [47]: tail = os.path.relpath(path, os.path.join(path, back)))

In [48]: tail
Out[48]: 'b\\c'
```

Aka no not that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple.  Convert both cwd and your input path into absolute paths and then just use startswith and slicing

```
path = os.path.abspath(path)
#Make sure you finish curDir with a path separator
#to avoid incorrect partial matches
curDir = os.path.abspath(".") + os.path.sep
if path.startswith(curDir):
    whatYouWant = path[len(curDir) - 1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem:

```
def gettail(path_, length):        
    elements = []
    for i in range(length):
        s = os.path.split(path_)
        elements.append(s[1])
        path_ = s[0] 

    outpath = elements.pop()
    while elements:
        outpath = os.path.join(outpath, elements.pop())
    return outpath
```

Output:

```
>>> print gettail(r"C:\foo\bar\baz\text.txt", 3)
    'bar\\baz\\text.txt'
```

Suggestions/improvements welcome.